# NodeJS download slower than chrome. Possible to simulate browser?

Tags: node.js, http, https, download, http-get

When attempting to download the audio file from [here](https://r7---sn-cxaaj5o5q5-tt1e6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1628835915&ei=67sVYeVMiIH-1w-MkJyAAg&ip=74.14.164.182&id=o-ABTB6CdkJnY0JnmvZ1p957saUas-cimK5MVQq4rQEmv2&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=zX&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-cxaaj5o5q5-tt1e6%2Csn-vgqsrnlk&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=7&pl=24&initcwndbps=1533750&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=oaEayCJMM9ca2WqDjLyf-gUG&gir=yes&clen=3009954&dur=190.001&lmt=1619468172687347&mt=1628814040&fvip=2&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=5532434&n=UsFoyxz833uj2jUtagG&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgQqQlhPuO7Frni0N-AYxxRfw-N2GVM2ELaxGky9GG2IICIB2Y_kJEYHpmL77-S6_-tfGkgwTGOv-wneFqDHZrtUGj&ratebypass=yes&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAJlRb2Ic3bA8ds1_bP8y3PihU6nPuLcLUoYc1NhSDRh6AiEAxQkDFaBs6Ho8lDIFWNXEd5r6fycPop9imfvJz500SOk%3D) with NodeJS, it takes 10+ seconds whereas the same download through the browser takes under a second. I've used loads of different request libraries which **might** suggest that the source limits the speed for non-browser requests??

If this is the case, would it be possible to somehow simulate a browser request or change some settings so that the NodeJS download is as fast as the browser download? Thanks!

EDIT: Heres some code that I've tried:

```
https.get({
  host: q.host,
  path: q.path,
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
}, (response) => {
  response.pipe(filePath).on('finish', () => {
    console.log('done')
})
```

Comment: You could try forging your useragent to appear as a browser. Might need cookies/etc to look like a browser too.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Just tried setting useragent (see edit) to no avail. I'm not sure if cookies are necessary because it downloads very quick in an incognito tab.

Comment: It seems likely that the browser is not immediately downloading the entire audio stream, but is instead loading it in pieces via byte ranges so that it can begin playing nearly immediately.  Whereas your nodejs code is trying to download the entire audio file.  I also see that it may be using the QUIC protocol (designed for faster downloads).

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand what you mean but when I go to it directly, the progress bar thing (where it shows how much is loaded) fills right to the end within a second which means its fully downloaded.

Comment: @Rohin12 - Are you 100% sure it's not fetching from your browser cache?

Comment: @jfriend00 100% sure. I testing in both incognito, and another browser altogether. Plus, the file itself is only a few megabytes so it's really strange NodeJS takes this long.

Comment: In the network tab in Chrome, it claims the original URL download was only a few bytes and then the request stays pending for a long time which makes me think the browser is actually using some other mechanism for the actual data transfer, perhaps the QUIC protocol.

Comment: For me, the requests end in approx. 1.5seconds. Heres a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/8ms9zi2.png

Comment: @jfriend00 I have no idea why, but it seems `  "headers": { "range": "bytes=0-"}` dramatically reduced the download time. I figured it out by right-clicking the network request and copy to NodeJS. Do you know what the headers mean?

Comment: Here's [some doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) on the "range" header.

Comment: @jfriend00 facing this issue again and this time the range header is not working. I am wondering if you could provide some more information on the QUIC protocol and how to get it working on NodeJS?

Comment: @Rohin12 - I'd suggest you open a new question and fill it with relevant details on the specific situation of your new problem.  In particular, if you can provide something that people could actually run and try out solutions, that would make it more likely people could provide an answer.

Comment: Since it's YouTube specific, I asked about it on relevant YTDL repos. Here's the pull: https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/pull/1022. Might be of interest